# Monthly reminder Email

Tags: designer-workflow

I'd like to create a monthly email reminder (the 1st of every month).  also would like actions to update "Due Date" + 1 month.  new to SP Designer 2013.  I dont see any Action to "Send email on the 1st of each month" is there a way with loop or some other action?

Answer (score 0):

Do want just a reminder email that is not tied to anything? Or one that is tied to a task that stops with the task is completed?

If just a reminder:

- create a recurring event in your Outlook calendar, or
- Create a recurring event in a SharePoint calendar, and then set an Alert on the calendar.

A workflow can loop and will follow this pattern: (A SharePoint 2013 style workflow)

[image]

The workflow has a Loop, and inside of the loop, an email Action and a Pause Action.
This example loops forever. More likely you would replace the "1 equals 1" with a test for a changed column, maybe the Status column of a task list, so a user will get a reminder until the task is completed.

Comment: email is tied to a form in the list.  i.e. it's time to do such and such.  i have yearly, monthly, quarterly things and i'm pulling variables out of the list and plugging them into the emails.  it just sucks that Microsoft doesnt give us an option to "send email on X day of the month" so we have to configure complicated loops and cant account for months being 31 days or 28 days.  Scheduled task setup would be nice!!